# How can I plot specific Excel data from two columns with conditions?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a huge spreadsheet of data that looks something like this:

| Date | IDNumber | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-10 | 1 | Apple |
| 2021-05-10 | 1 | Orange |
| 2021-05-10 | 2 | Apple |
| 2021-05-10 | 2 | Grape |
| 2021-06-10 | 5 | Apple |
| 2021-06-10 | 5 | Grape |
| 2021-06-10 | 5 | Apple |
| 2021-07-10 | 7 | Pear |
| 2021-07-10 | 7 | Orange |

I would like to use Python to parse/sort/plot these data where I can plot this as number of a specific item type for a specific ID number as a function of time. I'm envisioning a bar/scatter plot with the x-axis being time as month (but being able to change this time period would be key) and y-axis amount of each item.

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lsJB.png)

Really it would be awesome if I could pull out this information and put it into a new Excel sheet with new columns of date and item frequency.

Currently I'm using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('ExcelExample.xlsx',
                    usecols=("A:E"), sheet_name=('Data'))

df_Region1 = df.loc[(((df)["StateNumber"].isin([1]) & (df["CountyNumber"].isin([5,6]))) | ((df)["StateNumber"].isin([3]) & (df["CountyNumber"].isin([8]))))]
```

The last line of code is going from HUGE spreadsheet to a smaller one shown in my example table.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70322111/4961700 and add if() to control what data gets put in the list

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I didn't see anything in that post about Python code. It looked like that was all just Excel.

Comment: Yes, you missed your tagging Excel, as in you tagged it so I showed you an excel based possibility. But no worries I won't come back with an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean for that to come off insincere. I truly appreciate yours and anyone's help on here.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendaion is to filter your DataFrame based on your desired date range and count the unique items. Something like:

```
x = []
start_date = '2021-05-10'
end_date= '2021-05-20'
for item in df.item.unique():
    x.append(len(df[ (df['date'] >= start_date) & (df['date'] <= end_date)  & (df['item'] == item)]))
plt.plot(df.item.unique(), x, 'o')
```

Don't think that's the best way to do it, but I think it'll work in your case. Ypu can see documentation for `pd.value_counts` and `pd.groupby`. Also make sure you have already converted the date string to a date format using `pd.to_datetime`. Hope this clear things up.