# Excel: line chart from table

Tags: excel

I have this Excel table,

```
Product Param1 Param2   Param3  Param4 Param5   Date
 Alpha  89%     89%     100%    81%     89%    20/07/2023
 Beta   86%     57%     100%    0%      86%    20/07/2023
 Delta  83%     83%     100%    17%     83%    20/07/2023
 Omega  100%    100%    100%    0%      100%   20/07/2023
 Alpha  92%     89%     100%    81%     89%    21/07/2023
 Beta   87%     57%     100%    0%      86%    21/07/2023
 Delta  85%     83%     100%    17%     83%    21/07/2023
 Omega  100%    100%    100%    0%      100%   21/07/2023
 Alpha  96%     89%     100%    81%     89%    22/07/2023
 Beta   99%     57%     100%    0%      86%    22/07/2023
 Delta  93%     83%     100%    17%     83%    22/07/2023
 Omega  90%     100%    100%    0%      100%   22/07/2023
```

and I would like to create a line chart that shows the trend over time of the values in the "Param1" field for a single product, with the ability to select the desired product from a filter.

Let me explain it further: I would like a line chart with the dates "20/07/2023, 21/07/2023, and 22/07/2023" on the horizontal axis, and the values "89%, 92%, and 96%" on the vertical axis if the "Alpha" product is selected. However, if the "Beta" product is selected, the line chart should display the dates "20/07/2023, 21/07/2023, and 22/07/2023" on the horizontal axis, and the values "86%, 87%, and 99%" on the vertical axis.

Is it possible to achieve this behavior using standard Excel charts, or is it necessary to develop custom code for it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're looking for a Horizontal Bar Chart.

Comment: Do you have any good examples to suggest?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70322111/4961700 and edit to suit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, have a look at this:

Cell J3 is a unique list using unique()

Cols L,M and N list the items based on the selected product in cell J10 (a data validation drop down list)

The two blocks starting in cells A18 and A32 bring the relevant data down and replace FALSE with NA(), which is ignored by the charting function.

The chart just  needs titles etc, but you could add a data validation to choose any of params 1 through 5, but I leave that small improvement to you.

[image]